# Missing character (multiple markers at this line

Tags: java, android

Hi still new to Android and Java.

Please have a look at this code, I am getting multiple markers error and cant figure out where I am missing a character or  parenthesis. Its indicating the error on the last two parenthesis.

```
public class watsnuut extends Activity{      

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.watsnuut);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    final ProgressBar progess = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://kyknet.dstv.com/nuus/");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing `);` to your `setWebViewClient()`

Comment: multiple markers means that eclipse has more than one error or warnings in that line. Hover with your mouse over it to see what they are.

Comment: By convention, Java type names usually start with an uppercase letter, make **watsnutt** to **Watsnutt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close `setWebViewClient` method call

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add **});** in

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    });
```

instead of

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            progess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```